# How to open Eclipse -- tegra development pack -- in ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, tegra

After i installed "tegra development pack" on my ubuntu, the installation opened eclipse IDE for me and then i closed and then figured out that there isn't any shortcut or anything i could launch it from.

Update:

I followed "Venzen" solution till step 3 and used the filtering command. That showed me that there is another folder named "NVPACK" is located in username > NVPACK > eclipse which I didn't know about, I kept locking tipping in "eclipse" in the terminal.
Also, there is something stupid I did I would like to share; what happened here is that I kept looking at NVPACK installation folder at windows files not in linux files. (I'm using ubuntu in windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open a terminal and try to launch Eclipse from the command line:

```
$ eclipse
```

If this does not work it could mean that the `eclipse` binary was installed somewhere outside of your `PATH` and you will have to look for it. I am not familiar with Tegra, but here is a general purpose "process of elimination" to find a file in *nix:

1. update the locate database

   $ sudo updatedb
2. use the `which` command to interrogate the updated locate database

   $ which eclipse
3. you should have found it by now. If you haven't all is not lost - run the `locate` command just for good measure

   $ sudo locate eclipse

`locate` could potentially output lots of matches since it outputs any match to your search term whether its a file or a folder. If the output of `locate` scrolls off the screen then use `grep` to filter out only matches where `eclipse` is a file:

```
$ sudo locate eclipse | grep '.*eclipse$'
```

If this produces several matches then choose the `eclipse` file which resides in a `bin` folder.

If, by now, a file called eclipse has not yet shown itself, then there are 2 more options left - a long way and a short way...

1. use the `find` command
2. post the method (or source) from where you installed

either way, kindly post here should steps 1-3 above not reveal eclipse.